# Gridview Row Events not firing in UserControl

Tags: c#, gridview, user-controls, ascx, commandfield

I've got a pretty strange problem with my usercontrols that I'm working with. I'm coding some user controls to be used in a DotNetNuke module.

Basically I have a UserControl on my page that holds some controls and then there is a Placeholder where I am loading in a UserControl that has a GridView placed in it.

Basically here is my page structure

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlServiceType" Visible="false">
   <uc:ServiceType runat="server" ID="ServiceType" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Within that user control are some form elements and then the following:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phServices" />
```

That placeholder then has a user control added to it like so:

```
<p class="header"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblServiceHeader" Font-Bold="true" /></p>

<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvServices" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#eaeaea"  BorderStyle="None" GridLines="None"
AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="6" Width="100%" EnableViewState="false" OnRowEditing="gvServices_RowEditing">
```

When the user picks something in the DropDownList, I'm clearing the controls out of the Placeholder, and re-adding just a single UserControl for the set of records for whatever type they've picked like so

```
        _serviceID = e.Value;

        //Clear the controls out of the placeholder
        phServices.Controls.Clear();

        //Reset the count of grids for the OnInit() method
        Session["GridCount"] = 0;

        if (e.Value != "NULL")
        {
            PopulateServicesGrid(_service.GetServicesByFormType(Convert.ToInt32(e.Value)));
        }
        else
        {
            PopulateServicesGrid(_service.GetServicesByClient(Convert.ToInt32(_client)));
        }
```

And the PopulateServicesGrid method:

```
    private void PopulateServicesGrid(List<NOAService> services)
    {
        //Creates a LINQ grouping based on the Billing Codes
        //Allows a super easy creation of grids based on the grouped billing codes
        var query = services.Select(service => service.BillingCode).Distinct();
        foreach (string code in query)
        {
            var servicesByCode = services.Where(service => service.BillingCode == code).ToList();
            ServicesGrid servicesGrid = LoadControl("~/DesktopModules/LEL Modules/NOA/ServicesGrid.ascx") as ServicesGrid;
            Label lblServiceHeader = servicesGrid.FindControl("lblServiceHeader") as Label;
            GridView gvServices = servicesGrid.FindControl("gvServices") as GridView;

            phServices.Controls.Add(servicesGrid);
            servicesGrid.ID = code;
            lblServiceHeader.Text = servicesByCode[0].FormTypeName;
            gvServices.DataSource = servicesByCode;
            gvServices.DataBind();

            Session["GridCount"] = phServices.Controls.Count;

        }
    }
```

And on my ServiceType UserControl, on the PageInit, I'm readding the ServiceGrid usercontrol so that my grids show up across postbacks and aren't lost from the Placeholder

```
    void NOAServiceType_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(Session["GridCount"]); i++)
        {
            ServicesGrid servicesGrid = LoadControl("~/DesktopModules/LEL Modules/NOA/ServicesGrid.ascx") as ServicesGrid;
            phServices.Controls.Add(servicesGrid);

        }
    }
```

The grids populate successfully and everything seems to work just fine. But for some reason, on my GridView, I have a CommandField of

```
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" EditText="Edit" UpdateText="Update" 
        EditImageUrl="~/images/LELModules/appbar.edit.rest.png" CancelImageUrl="~/images/LELModules/appbar.close.rest.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/images/LELModules/appbar.check.rest.png"
        ButtonType="Image" CausesValidation="false" />
```

When I click my Edit command on the Grid row, nothing happens. My grid doesn't lose its rows, the control is still there, everything seems like it should be ok. The `RowEditing` event doesn't fire until I click it a second time.

Any idea why this might be occuring?

**UPDATE**: I've managed to figure out that my SelectedIndexChanged handlers are effectively resetting the `DataSource` on the Grid contained by the UserControl when they are readded to the PlaceHolder. When the CommandField (Edit) is clicked though, the `Init` fires for the UserControl that holds the placeholder

```
ServiceType UserControl < `Init` fires here
   -Form elements
   -Placeholder which holds
      --UserControl with GridView
```

The `Init` method loads up new instances of the UserControl and adds them to the PlaceHolder, but the DataSource is `null`. With `EnableViewState=true` it looks like the data is still bound, but if I handle `PreRender`, I can see that the `DataSource` on my `gvServices | null`

Is it even possible to edit rows like this on a GridView that is being added dynamically to a PlaceHolder over and over?

**FIXED** I found out what the issue was after referring to this article 
    http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/Feb/24/Overriding-ClientID-and-UniqueID-on-ASPNET-controls

It got me thinking, what if the IDs were getting changed? The controls are way nested. So I went and put a watch on the GridView's ID, ClientID, and UniqueID just to see. When the Control is loaded on my `Init` handler, it's assigned a super generic ID when it's added.

```
private void PopulateServicesGrid(List<NOAService> services)
{
    //Creates a LINQ grouping based on the Billing Codes
    //Allows a super easy creation of grids based on the grouped billing codes
    var query = services.Select(service => service.BillingCode).Distinct();
    foreach (string code in query)
    {
        var servicesByCode = services.Where(service => service.BillingCode == code).ToList();
        ServicesGrid servicesGrid = LoadControl("~/DesktopModules/LEL Modules/NOA/ServicesGrid.ascx") as ServicesGrid;
        Label lblServiceHeader = servicesGrid.FindControl("lblServiceHeader") as Label;
        GridView gvServices = servicesGrid.FindControl("gvServices") as GridView;

        phServices.Controls.Add(servicesGrid);
        **servicesGrid.ID = code;**
        lblServiceHeader.Text = servicesByCode[0].FormTypeName;
        gvServices.DataSource = servicesByCode;
        gvServices.DataBind();

        Session["GridCount"] = phServices.Controls.Count;

    }
}
```

I was setting the ID as something else. So when I was hitting the Edit RowCommand on my grid, it was reloading the controls again on `Init` and the IDs were being changed back from my custom set code (T2020, pulled from my database) to the generic ID again, it didn't know how to fire the event.

I hope this helps someone as I've lost at least 12 hours fixing this problem.